# Create iTerm2 startup configuration

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

iTerm allows one to save a window arrangement, I'd like to know if (and then how) I can extend this facility to do the following:

1. Save the name of each tab so that each tab in the restored window gets a specific name automatically on startup. This should apply to each split pane in a tab. Solutions involving PROMPT_COMMAND fail to achieve both of these goals for me, without me manually exporting a desired PROMPT_COMMAND for each pane in each tab.
2. Get some startup commands to run on designated tabs/panes. For example i'd like to start ipython notebook on a specific pane in a specific tab, and maybe initiate a SSH connection to a machine on another pane etc.

So far I've exhausted all attempts to seeks answers to these!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that iTerm is scriptable by AppleScript. Here are some examples: https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/AppleScript